# regex string enclosed by double quote or single quotes

Tags: python, regex

I got this regex:

```
(\s|'|\")((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]))([a-z0-9]{8})(\s|'|\")
```

to search for strings of length 8 having one lower case character and one digit. The string needs to be enclosed by space, quote or double quote.

What does not work in the expression: something like this would be accepted:
`"1234567a'`. If string starts with `'` it should end with `'`, when starting with `"` it should end by `"` etc.

I am not very strong at regexes so let me ask if there is a better way to enforce same character for begin and end without repeating regex 3 times?

Comment: Are you validating a string? Try `r'''^([\s'"])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})\1$'''`

Comment: that one does the job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the same char at the end of the string as the one at its start, you may use a [*backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the char once it is captured into a capturing group.

Besides, to make sure  you match at the start of the string, add `^` anchor at the start of the string and `$` anchor at the end of string:

```
r'''^([\s'"])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\1$'''
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZNKiXi/2)

The `([\s'"])` is a capturing group with ID 1, so, the `\1` backreference at the end matches the same text as is stored in Group 1 memory buffer.